# java doubly linked list delete a node

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

I was given an integer called key as the parameter. I need to know how to delete a node at position key. Ndata is from my Node class.

```
    public void deleteNode(int key)
    {
       Node<E> temp = head; 
       while(temp.Ndata != key)//gives me error as not compatible types.    
       {
            temp = temp.next;
       }
       if(temp == head)
            head = temp.next;
       else
            temp.prev.next = temp.next;
       if(temp == tail)
            tail == temp.prev;
       else
            temp.prev.next = temp.next;
     }
```

Comment: What type is `node.Ndata`? Why isn't it an `int`?

Comment: its type T because I am using generics

Comment: It's also not clear if `key` is supposed to be the node position of the element to delete, or the node value - your question says `key` is the position, but then your code seems to look for node value (`Ndata`). To add to the confusion, one of the two answers so far assumes value and the other is assuming position...

Comment: key is the element that should be deleted . if key = 5 then the 5th element needs to be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you need to find the node which is storing the value `key`, you need to do either:

```
Node<Integer> temp = head;
```

or:

```
public void deleteNode(E key)
```

This ensures type compatibility for your generic Node class.

Comment: I did the first but head is type Node<E> and it does not work if I cast it to Node<Integer> head.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned that, you need to delete a node at position `key`. Here is how the code should be:

```
public void deleteNode (int key) {
    // those are base cases
    if (key >= length)
        key = length - 1;
    elseif (key < length)
        key = 0;

    if (head == null) // if list is empty
        return;

    if (key == 0){ // it means you have to remove head
        head = head.getNext(); //assuming you have getters and setters
        if (head == null)
            tail = null;
    } else {
        Node<E> temp = head;
        // iterate to that position ie. key
        for (int index = 0; index < key; index++){
            temp = temp.getNext();
        }
        // this is most important part
        temp.getNext().setPrev(temp.getPrev());
        temp.getPrev().setNext(temp.getNext());
    }
    length--; //since you deleted element the list is now 1 less
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This helped a lot but to make sure I got it I need to create an int variable called length in my class. Then keep track of it through all my insert methods.

Comment: yes, I made an assumption that you will be tracking all your inserts and deletes

Comment: When I ran it like this it only deleted the first node every time no matter what I do.

Comment: Logically, the code is correct. The head will get deleted only when your `key == 0`. It will be good if you use a debugger to check if the nodes are updating correctly. That will be helpful to identify the trivial mistake that might be happening.

Comment: I have a similar problem, do you think you can help me out. I've been searching everywhere on the internet, through my books and I'm getting nowhere.